# How to calculated Confidence Interval for autocorrelated and lognormally distributed data?

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, autocorrelation, lognormal-distribution

My data is autocorrelated and is lognormally distributed, how can I calculate Confidence interval of that set of data?

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'confidence interval of that set of data' and also depends on your model for the serial dependence(/the model for the joint distribution of observations).

Comment: My data is real time chemical concentrations with n=1000. I found that it is lognormally distributed so I was thinking about calculating CI using Land's equation. However, I also found that the data is autocorrelated (supposed lag1 autocorrelation=0.8). So I understand that Standard deviation of this data is biased. Should I correct the SD and use the corrected SD in the CI equation for lognormal distribution data?

Comment: There are many different ways that data can have some specific correlation at lag 1; what is your model for the joint distribution, or at least for the joint distribution of two consecutive lags?

Comment: @Glen_b I will have to take a look at the model for the joint distribution and I'll let you know. Thank you very much for your comments!

Comment: Specifically, autocorrelation might often be modelled using an AR model, but it's an additive model, which doesn't play well with lognormal margins.

Comment: @Glen_b I did not know about that before, thank you for the information.

Comment: This is what caused me to ask what kind of joint model you might consider; something that would give lognormal distributions for the variables (whether marginal or conditional, but you seemed to be implying marginal lognormal) but which also had a particular value for autocorrelation. What does it look like if you plot $y_t$ vs $y_{t-1}$? Of course one might try looking at taking the logs and seeing whether a simple model (like an AR) is suitable in the logs.

Answer (score 3):

Take the log of the data to generate a new time series which is normally distributed, then apply the corrections to the effective degrees of freedom and bias of sample statistics from these papers, both of which can be downloaded for free online:

- Zięba, Andrzej. ["Effective number of observations and unbiased estimators of variance for autocorrelated data-an overview."](http://www.metrology.pg.gda.pl/no201001.html#p003) Metrology and Measurement Systems 17.1 (2010): 3-16.
- Zięba, Andrzej, and Piotr Ramza. ["Standard Deviation of the Mean of Autocorrelated Observations Estimated with the Use of the Autocorrelation Function Estimated From the Data."](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/mms.2011.xviii.issue-4/v10178-011-0052-x/v10178-011-0052-x.xml) Metrology and Measurement Systems 18.4 (2011): 529-542.

Answer (score 0):

It does in the exponent.
exp^(ARIMA(1,0,1))

Where you calculate the arima on the lognormal difference between time points.
ln(x_i / x_i+1) ~ ARIMA(1,0,1)

Note, this needs to have uniform intervals or everything breaks, but thats for anything time series related usually. Infinite crossing and all that.